# FTP login fails in php

Tags: php, azure, ftp

I am trying to connect FTP from php. `FTP_ADDRESS`, `FTP_USERNAME` and `FTP_PASSWORD` are pre-defined constants.

**CODE**

```
$conn = ftp_connect(FTP_ADDRESS);
$login = ftp_login($conn, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
//ftp_pasv($conn, true);
```

I am getting below error,

```
Severity: Warning
Message: ftp_login(): Microsoft FTP Service
Filename: controllers/user.php
```

**Server Info: Windows Azure**.
I also tried by adding passive connection by,

```
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
```

But, I am still getting the same error message.

**EDIT**

I tried with this:

```
var_dump($conn);

Output:
resource(3) of type (FTP Buffer)
```

Comment: Please add more debugging... does ftp_connect succeed or fail ?

Answer (score 0):

Initial, check to see if ftp_connect is available e.g.

```
if (function_exists('ftp_connect')) {
      'Do your FTP stuff above
} else {
      echo 'FTP not available';
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to access php.ini or alternative to activate ftp in Azure.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the documentation you have an incorrect username or password.

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. If login fails, PHP will also throw a warning.
[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php)